# PostgreSQL cannot work when opens SSL on Windows 10

Tags: postgresql, database, windows-10, ssl

I am not sure this topic will fit here but I don't know ask it where.

I am trying to open the SSL of PostgreSQL 10.16 on Windows10.

I read a lot of documents about creating an SSL certificate to PostgreSQL but documents spend on Windows 10 are rare and don't detail.

These are the steps which I did:

**Step 1**, I download the OpenSSL version of Windows from https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html

and install it with the path C:\OpenSSL-Win64, setting system variable.

**Step 2**, I use cmd.exe run as an admin to create server.key with command-line:

```
  genrsa -out server.key 4096
```

,  set appropriate permission and owner on the private key file (here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51463654)

```
  icacls server.key /reset
  icacls server.key /inheritance:r /grant:r "CREATOR OWNER:F"
```

[image]

*continue* to create the server certificate:

```
 req -new -x509 -days 1826 -key server.key -out server.crt
```

**Step 3**,

Since I am self-signing, I use the server certificate as the trusted root certificate, so I have 3 files: server.key, server.crt, and root.crt (this is a copy of server.crt)

I cut these three files to C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\data

**Step 4**, I am setting postgresql.conf:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
port = 5432
ssl=on
ssl_cert_file = 'server.crt'
ssl_key_file = 'server.key'
ssl_ca_file = 'root.crt'
```

and add command-line to the end of pg_hba.conf:

[image]

**Finally**, I get an error as below when I restart my PostgreSQL

[image]

and in my log of PostgreSQL:

[image]

I suspect PostgreSQL did not read the 3 files that I put in its data directory.

I have referenced these documents

https://www.howtoforge.com/postgresql-ssl-certificates
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43959324/chmod-og-rwx-server-key-in-windows
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/ssl-tcp.html

I have been messing with it for many days and I don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: [dba.se] is the SE place for pure database questions.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/ is more appropriate.

Comment: fyi only root.crt is needed on the client side. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/ssl-tcp.html

Comment: if your client/server are the same PC/host SSL is not needed. https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/131637/is-it-necessary-to-enable-ssl-for-client-and-server-that-run-in-same-machine

Comment: You're right. But my purpose uses Postgis to connect to Qgis, next I will package Qgis project with Q-field plugin and offer it to my phone device for collect data in the field. I think I need SSL to secure my data when data are transmitted over the internet to my server.